# Use jQuery to wrap text after element

Tags: jquery, html, word-wrap

What I have:

A checkbox inside a label.

```html
<label for="foo">
  <input type="checkbox" id="foo" />bar
</label>
```

What I need:

Using jQuery, I need to to wrap the text following the checkbox (i.e. "bar"), in a span element.

```
<label for="foo">
  <input type="checkbox" id="foo" /><span>bar</span>
</label>
```

What I've tried:

```
$('label').wrapInner('<span></span>');
```

This does not exclude the checkbox as required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to wrap the text node, you could filter the contents of the element based on whether the `nodeType` property is 3 (which is the value of a text node), and wrap the returned text node.

```
$('label').contents().filter(function () {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<span></span>');
```

Alternatively, if you know the text node will always be the next sibling of the `input` element, you could select the next sibling node using the `nextSibling` property:

```
$('label input').each(function () {
  $(this.nextSibling).wrap('<span></span>');
});
```

Comment: Awesome... I thought it was possible without the use of `nodeType`. Check my answer.

Comment: The latter approach indeed applies in my particular case.