# How do I style plain text within elements using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery’s .css() method, how can I style the plain text **after** `span.foo` for each list item in the following HTML structure?

Specifically, I need to get the text **after** each `span.foo` (**without knowing what it is**) and color it red.

```
<li>
    not this text
    <span class='foo'>not this text</span>
    this text
</li>
<li>
    not this text
    <span class=“foo”>not this text</span>
    and this text
</li>
<li>
    not this text
    <span class='foo'>not this text</span>
    and this text as well
</li>

$().css('color', 'red');
```

Comment: _"without changing the HTML itself"_ - that's not possible. You will have to wrap the text in something that can be styled. Maybe not hard-coded in the markup but at least programmatically with jQuery/JavaScript

Comment: Andreas is right. The text on its own cannot be styled - only HTML elements can. So either you style the whole `li` (possibly with a clause to exclude the inner `span` if that's appropriate) or you modify the HTML so that that bit of text is wrapped within its own element (e.g. another span perhaps) and is therefore style-able. As mentioned, you needn't necessarily modify the raw HTML if that's impractical...script could be used to manipulate things instead once the page is loaded.

Comment: @Andreas is right. At least put it inside a span called something called "colored". Will be easy task than, and do not change anything that you already have.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I would be able to wrap the plain text in an element using jQuery. I have edited my question to reflect that.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy the question very clearly refers to modifying the text  **after** each span.foo, not **within** it. I suggest you read it a bit more carefully.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use jQuery to wrap text after element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34834061/use-jquery-to-wrap-text-after-element)

Comment: " I would be able to wrap the plain text in an element using jQuery" ...and have you made any attempt to try and do so, or look into how it might be done? We don't want to re-invent the wheel if a solution already exists somewhere. I see Andreas has already found a possible answer. Did you do any research of your own at all? We're not really here to do your googling for you, to be honest.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to select the span and than you need to select the text element after it. To style it, you will need to wrap it in another element.

```js
$('ul li span').each( (i, elem) => { // function (i, elem) {
   $(elem.nextSibling).wrap('<span class="special"/>')
});
```

```css
.special {
  color: #CFC;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li>
    not this text
    <span class='foo'>not this text</span>
    this text
</li>
<li>
    not this text
    <span class=“foo”>not this text</span>
    and this text
</li>
<li>
    not this text
    <span class='foo'>not this text</span>
    and this text as well
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is 100% true to the question as the jQuery will alter the html, but you do not need to alter the html at source (which I think is the sentiment behind the statement).

```js
$(function () {
    $("li").each(function (item) {
        $(this).contents().filter(function () {
            return this.nodeType === 3;
        }).last().wrap("<span class='text-red'></span>");
    });
});
```

```css
.text-red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li>
    not this text
    <span class='foo'>not this text</span>
    this text
</li>
<li>
    not this text
    <span class=“foo”>not this text</span>
    and this text
</li>
<li>
    not this text
    <span class='foo'>not this text</span>
    and this text as well
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

It takes a little bit of finagling, since it's a raw text node, not an element, but here.

Naturally, to style the node, we need to wrap it in something; I chose an anonymous span that's styled inline.

```js
$("span.foo").each(function() {
  var node = this.nextSibling;
  if (node.nodeType == 3) { // see if the next node is actually a text node
    var $el = $("<span>")
      .text(node.textContent)
      .css("color", "orange"); // create a wrapper element and style it
    node.replaceWith($el[0]); // replace the text node with our new span element.
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  not this text
  <span class='foo'>not this text</span> this text
</li>
<li>
  not this text
  <span class="foo">not this text</span> and this text
</li>
<li>
  not this text
  <span class='foo'>not this text</span> and this text as well
</li>
```